# Adding new java based PMD rule in eclipse pmd plugin

Tags: java, pmd

How can we add a new java based pmd rule in eclipse pmd plugin?

I am getting following error:

**Invalid Class implementation.The class must be in plugin classpath and implement the rule interface.**

I have extended rule class with AbstractRule class.

Comment: For a different (but famous) [eclipse-pmd](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/) plugin, please also see [answer to this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983135/how-to-add-custom-jar-to-the-eclipse-pmd-plugin/29461426#29461426)