# How to Add custom JAR to the "eclipse-pmd" plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd, eclipse-pmd

Installed the ***Eclipse PMD plugin*** (written by *Philip Graf*) from [here](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/).  I tried to associate a custom PMD rule classes JAR but couldn't find a provision for it.  This JAR contains custom rule classes (that `extends AbstractJavaRule` indirectly).

So is there any way to configure *eclipse-pmd* plugin to accept this custom JAR?

My `custompmd.jar` has this structure:

> custompmd.jar
>  └─com/pmd/custom
>                └─AvoidHardcodingRule.class
>                └─AvoidCatchWithoutLogErrorRule.class
>                └─etc...

Simply putting it in `plugins` directory didn't help.  One of the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3564152/248847) suggests a solution but that's for a *different* [plugin](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse/).

**[UPDATE]**
I am currently thinking of editing one of the `eclipse\plugins\ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.BLAHBLAH.jar`, add `custompmd.jar` into the `lib` folder and updating `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` file by appending the JAR information in the **Bundle-ClassPath:** section.  Is it the right practice as patching the plugin JAR seems ugly to me?

**[UPDATE]**
The above approach didn't work.

Any of you Eclipse gurus know how to crack it?

**[UPDATE]**
I cracked it by myself.

**[UPDATE]**
Although the below solution works, it is a maintenance nightmare.  Whenever, I change the `custompmd.jar`, I have to update the plugin JAR as well everytime, which is tedious.  Is there a clean and neat solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your custom rule classes if you add your jar as an Eclipse plug-in fragment to your Eclipse installation. The host of the plug-in fragment must be `ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.core`.

To convert the jar to a plug-in fragment you have to modify the file `MANIFEST.MF` file and add a few manifest headers. The following is a complete manifest of an Eclipse plug-in fragment:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Custom PMD Rules
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.example.customrules
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Fragment-Host: ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.core;bundle-version="1.4.1"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

You can choose your own values for the headers `Bundle-Name`, `Bundle-SymbolicName` and `Bundle-Version`. The value of the header `Bundle-ManifestVersion` must be `2`. `Fragment-Host` must contain the symbolic name of the host bundle `ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.core` and optionally the version of eclipse-pmd you have installed. `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment` specifies the minimum execution environment the plug-in fragment requires. Its value is `JavaSE-1.7` if you compiled it with Java 7 or `JavaSE-1.8` if you used Java 8.

Once you changed the manifest of your jar you can copy it into the folder `dropins` of your eclipse installation. Your plug-in fragment is installed when you start Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

## Finally figured it out myself !

*(I should've got it working in my previous attempt itself, but due to a stale `custompmd.jar` because of failed ANT task, it didn't work that time).*

Step-by-step:

1. Copy the `ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.core_<blahblah#>.jar` from `plugins` directory into a temp directory.
2. Open the JAR in temp directory using 7-Zip software
3. Add `custompmd.jar` into the `lib` directory.
4. Edit `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, append this string `,lib/custompmd.jar` at the end of `Bundle-Classpath:`
5. Close 7-Zip (and accept the Save dialog).
6. Take a backup of the existing `/plugins/ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.core_<blahblah#>.jar` and replace it with this temp jar.
7. Exit Eclipse and Restart

Comment: Modifing a plug-in from eclipse-pmd has the disadvantage that you lose your modifications when a new version of eclipse-pmd is released and the plug-in is replaced with its newer version. If you convert your jar to a plug-in fragment and install it in Eclipse you don't have this problem. My answer shows you how to do that.

Comment: @Everyone, please see above (accepted answer) for a maintainable (and authentic as it comes from the author of the plugin) solution.