# How to add custom Java rules for Eclipse PMD plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I’m using the pmd plugin on eclipse and I need to create my custom rules. I created my java class dependent on the AbstractJavaRule class and created my ruleset. But I can't import everything into pmd eclipse.
I did a lot of research and tried different suggested solutions, but nothing worked. Here is what I tried:

- Window -> Preferences -> PMD -> Rules configuration -> Import ruleset
- Window -> Preferences -> PMD -> Rules configuration -> Add a rule

For this method I created a jar containing my java class defining my rule and my ruleset in different packages. I then edited the MANIFEST.MF files and placed my jar in the lib/ folder as described on this post:
[How to Add custom JAR to the "eclipse-pmd" plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983135/how-to-add-custom-jar-to-the-eclipse-pmd-plugin)

But after clicking add rule, when I enter my rule implementation class, I get an "invalid rule class" error.

- Right click on project -> Properties -> PMD -> Use the configured ruleset in a project file (and I chose my ruleset.xml present in the project)
- I also read this post : [Adding new java based PMD rule in eclipse pmd plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564152/adding-new-java-based-pmd-rule-in-eclipse-pmd-plugin)

Neither method worked.

If you have an idea to help me solve my problem, I’m interested.